# Чистка кеша Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

Как очистить кеш в ардуино уно. Я использую микроконтроллер для управления цветом и частотой моргания rgb-светодиодом. Управляю Arduino при помощи Bluetooth HC-06. С телефона посылается значение цвета и задержки. Нужно иногда чистить кеш и обнулять эти значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0; // инициализация функции обнуления значений

resetFunc(); //вызов функции в нужном нам месте
```